# pytest does not find .coveragerc configs

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py

I am trying to run pytest with coverage output, using a `.coveragerc` file.

First of all, here is my folder structure:

```
playground/
├─ excercise.01/
│  ├─ calculator.py
│  ├─ test_calculator.py
├─ .coveragerc
```

Then, inside the `exercise.01` folder (as it contains my test) I tried to run:

```bash
pytest --cov-config=../.coveragerc
```

And it just gives me this output, without the coverage:

```
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                       

exercise.01\test_calculator.py ..  [100%] 

=========== 2 passed in 0.06s ===========
```

> I tried to run at the root folder as well.

Here is the content of the `.coveragerc`:

```
[tool:pytest]
addopts = --cov --cov-branch --cov-fail-under=90 --cov-report html

[run]
omit = test_*
```

The desired output should be as follows:

```
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                       

exercise.01\test_calculator.py ..                              [100%] 

------- coverage: platform win32, python 3.9.13-final-0 --------
Coverage HTML written to dir htmlcov

FAIL Required test coverage of 90% not reached. Total coverage: 84.62%

========================= 2 passed in 0.38s =========================
```

> I find this results running:
>
> ```
> pytest --cov=exercise.01 --cov-branch --cov-fail-under=90 --cov-report html
> ```
>
> Which is exactly the `addopts` found inside the `.coveragerc` file. That is why I know pytest cannot find the file `.coveragerc`

I wonder why it is not working?

Just to add some more information as it might be helpful, I am using Python 3.9.13 and this is what I have on my `requirements.txt`:

```
attrs==22.1.0
coverage==6.4.4
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
packaging==21.3
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.11.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pytest==7.1.3
pytest-cov==3.0.0
tomli==2.0.1
typing_extensions==4.3.0
zipp==3.8.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.coveragerc files don't accept `[tool:pytest]` sections.  That's something that can go in a setup.cfg or pyproject.toml file.  You are mixing syntaxes.

Comment: Awesome! I renamed the `.coveragerc` file to `setup.cfg` and it worked!

Comment: Could you provide where can I find proper documentation stating what should or should not put in the .coveragerc file? Or somewhere stating that placing `[tool:pytest]` in it is wrong?